# Rails 3 with HTTPS and SSL is not working (only showing default page of nginx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, web-deployment

Configuring Rails 3 with nginx to use HTTPS and SSL is not working. It shows Nginx's default page(the page with text --> Welcome to nginx!)

I have written `config.force_ssl = true` in application.rb

My nginx's Config file is as follows

```
# server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    # root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    # index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    # server_name localhost;

    # location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    # }

    # location /doc/ {
        # alias /usr/share/doc/;
        # autoindex on;
        # allow 127.0.0.1;
        # deny all;
    # }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
        # For example, return an error code
        #return 418;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #   fastcgi_index index.php;
    #   include fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
#}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

My site was working fine before this change(without https)

the steps I followed were

1. add `config.force_ssl = true` in application.rb
2. `sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/example`
3. changed `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example` as shown above
4. `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example`
5. `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: Are you using phusion passenger?

Comment: no I am using unicorn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the ssl's fault. You did not setup nginx correctly.

Nginx is only a proxy and you must pass the request to your rails app.

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

Comment: thanx... this is the issue... but still after writing above code I am getting `502 Bad Gateway`... when i seee unicorn.log I don't see any request

Comment: Thanx finally solved it by using `proxy_pass http://localhost;`(without 3000)
thanks really i was stuck here for long time :D. Thank you